# Create a Grok Pattern

Tags: grok

2021-10-06 03:57:29 Actual Memory:2.56 GB

I want to create a custom grok pattern for this log using this
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{DATA:Memory}
but it displays that nothing matches

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the grok pattern that matches your log:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:not_needed}%{NUMBER:actual_memory}
```

I have used the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to validate the grok pattern.

**Output:**
[image]